# How can I retrieve popular users from GitHub?

Tags: javascript, github, github-api

I am trying to get a list of popular repos and users on GitHub.

Their [API has an example](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-users) to find users given some criteria that must be sent under the `q` query param, this is a required parameter but I am not sure how to send it as 'empty'

The query should list users and sort by followers, I am close but I am not sure what to send in `q`

```
`https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${WHAT_WHOULD_GO_HERE}&sort=followers&order=desc`
```

Just for reference, I was also trying to get popular repos and this is possible with the following query and it works just fine:

```
curl https://api.github.com/search/repositories\?q\=stars:\>1+language:javascript\&sort\=stars\&order\=desc\&type\=Repositories
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fiddling around I got the answer:

```
curl https://api.github.com/search/users\?q\=followers:\>1000\&page\=1\&per_page\=10\&sort\=followers\&order\=desc
```

The query is based on Github's own popular list which has some clues in its own URL, the query above returns the exact same result

```
https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=followers%3A%3E%3D1000&ref=searchresults&s=followers&type=Users
```

The `q` query param needs only this:

- **followers**: >1000,

Plus some sorting as described in the question:

- **sort**: by the followers count,
- **order**: descendent

Answer (score 1):

You can run a query by specifying the follower limit, repository language, and page on the Github API. If you can configure the queries correctly, you will get what you want.

**Sample query**

```
`https://api.github.com/search/users?q=repos:followers:<1000&language:javascript&page=1&per_page=100`
```

For example, I can fetch all users with more than 2000 followers. This is also getting a kind of popular users.

```
`https://api.github.com/search/users?q=repos:followers:%3E2000&language:javascript&page=1&per_page=100`
```

Response

```
{
  "total_count": 321,
  "incomplete_results": false,
  "items": [
    {
      "login": "vim-scripts",
      "id": 443562,
      "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjQ0MzU2Mg==",
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/443562?v=4",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/vim-scripts",
      ...
}
```

Comment: That's great, although a List of popular users should be language agnostic, your query is great to get users with 1000+ followers who have ${Some_Language} repos?, also it's missing some sorting, very helpful nonetheless!

Comment: Can you please update your answer with this in mind? and I will happily accept your answer

Comment: Do you want to fetch users with more than 1000 followers in any language?